# Is there a way to do USB debugging on the Kindle Fire?

Tags: android

I use to email my apps to my kindle and then run them.  My app is now to big to email.  Is there a way to debug your app (usb port from eclipse) on the kindle????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindle Fire always has USB Debugging mode on.
You can enable USB Debugging on the Kindle Fire HD by pulling down the notifications      drawer, tapping More > Security > Enable ADB

Comment: Hi,Thak you, all this time i have been emailing my apps to the kindle to test them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is covered [in Amazon's documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/connect-adb.html). While they do not publish Linux instructions, I believe that they are the same as the ones shown for OS X.